# can not insert float or decimal to mysql db

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert the value `33.55555` to database. Even after changing mysql row to `float` or `decimal`, I am unable to do so correctly.
mysql:

```
ALTER TABLE `test` CHANGE `test1` `test1` DECIMAL( 10,10 ) NOT NULL
```

after inserting `33.55555` it is converted to `0.9999999999` via this sql command

```
ALTER TABLE `test` CHANGE `test1` `test1` FLOAT( 10,10 ) NOT NULL
```

`33.55555` is converted to `1.0000000000`

Answer (score 5):

Your DECIMAL() and FLOAT() declarations are off. The first parameter is how long you want the number to be, the second parameter is how many of those are decimals. So when you say FLOAT(10,10) you are saying give me a column that is 10 digits long with 10 of those digits after the decimal point.

Decimal and Float are also different in their terms of approximation. Decimals are fixed point values while floats are floating point values.

The .999999999 and 1.000000 are the maximum values for the columns.

Try this to insert 35.55555:

```
ALTER TABLE `test` CHANGE `test1` `test1` DECIMAL( 7,5 ) NOT NULL
```

Comment: thanks @Blaise Swanwick. `33.55555` is a test.i want to use maximum of left and right decimal point and i want to correctly inserted to db. for example after inserting `109291.2` this is not correct `109291.2031`. `031` added after inserting end of `109291.2`

Comment: @TuxWorld http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html Contains some reading. The maximum amt of data you can store in a decimal field is beyond my knowledge. But I do know I would rather use a decimal field over a float field if I needed precision.